# Question on "Converting Maven project of Mahout into Eclipse project"

Tags: eclipse, maven, mahout

While installing the open-source software like Mahout, I read some notes like

Convert Maven project of Mahout into Eclipse project

What does this mean? What's the difference between a Maven project and Eclipse project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) if you haven't already done it.

Enter the command prompt or a shell and navigate to the directory where the Mahout is located (there's a `pom.xml` file). Type the command:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

which will create project files for Eclipse and open the project in Eclipse.

No conversion is needed. Eclipse supports Maven projects, and vice-versa.

Difference between these two projects yield from the difference of the tools. Eclipse is an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) and [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_tool) is a build tool. In fact, IDE is a superset of a build tool. That's why Eclipse may use Maven for building. Common properties between the projects relate to how the build is being done and Eclipse has a set of properties aimed to persist the state between programming sessions.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I followed the instruction and got it worked. I am also interested in knowing the difference between a Maven project and an eclipse project.